# Count в sql запросе?

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT
    exam.id,
    exam.Nazvanie,
    COUNT(StudentsEkzamen.IdStudenta) AS countStudents //Количество студентов на этом экзамене
FROM ekzameni
INNER JOIN StudentsEkzamen 
    ON StudentsEkzamen.IdEkzamena=exam.id 
GROUP BY StudentsEkzamen.IdEkzamena
```

Запрос работает, если есть хотя бы 1 студент на экзамене. Если же нет - строка не выводится. Как мне в этом случае подставить 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inner join` добавляет строку в выборку только если соответствующие строки есть в обеих соединяемых таблицах. Так как в вашем случае соответствующие записи в таблице `StudentsEkzamen` могут отсутствовать, вам следет использовать `left join` - этот тип соединения таблиц включает строку в выборку если она есть только в первой таблице (в вашем случае - в таблице `ekzameni`).

[Больше информации по типам соединений таблиц в SQL.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 3):

Замените `inner join` на `left join` и будет вам счастье